# Direct sum of exact sequences?

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra, exact-sequence, direct-sum

In Hatcher's Algebraic Topology textbook, he has been referring to "direct sum of exact sequences". As far as I know he's never defined this and I can't find what I'm looking for online.

Without a precise definition I can only guess what he means but I'm not entirely sure.

For example, he refers to taking the direct sum of free resolutions of abelian groups $H$ and $H'$ to obtain a free resolution for $H \oplus H'$.

> What exactly does he mean here?

Comment: Direct sum componentwise.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just take the direct sum term-by term.  Explicitly, suppose $$\dots\stackrel{f_3}\to X_2\stackrel{f_2}\to X_1\stackrel{f_1}\to X_0$$ and $$\dots\stackrel{g_3}\to Y_2\stackrel{g_2}\to Y_1\stackrel{g_1}\to Y_0$$ are two sequences of maps of (say) abelian groups.  Their direct sum is then the sequence $$\dots\stackrel{h_3}\to X_2\oplus Y_2\stackrel{h_2}\to X_1\oplus Y_1\stackrel{h_1}\to X_0\oplus Y_0$$ where the maps $h_n:X_n\oplus Y_n\to X_{n-1}\oplus Y_{n-1}$ are defined by $h_n(x,y)=(f_n(x),g_n(y))$.  It is straightforward to check that if the two original sequences were exact, then so is the direct sum.

Comment: This was my guess about what it meant, and Berci confirmed it initially. This is a more complete answer though and hopefully anyone else who is confused by the lack of the definition in Hatcher will be able to come to this answer.